# grails error on save: cannot cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction

Tags: grails

Having trouble creating an object "from scratch" (in code instead of from forms) in Grails.  The following is the code snippet from a method in a controller (Assessment).

```
def newVol = new Vol(
              volType:type,
                app: assessmentInstance.app,
                assessment:assessmentInstance,
                dateFound: assessmentInstance.assDate,
                urlParam: url,
                volName: "TEST",
                volNote: "TEST"
         )

        newVol.save(validate:false,flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

result is this error:

```
Class
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
Message
ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
```

the id is mapped to a generator in the Vol class:

```
   static mapping = {
    id column:'vol_id'

    id generator: 'sequence',params:[sequence:'scan_sequence']
}
```

I really don't understand how a save could be thought of as a read-only transaction.  I tried messing around with the @transactional settings on my domain class, first putting readOnly to false and then removing the @transactional but it did not change things.  It looks like I should look for alternatives to using a database sequence.  What do you think?

**UPDATE**
removed the readonly=true from the controller where the above code lives and that worked.  But... what are the side effects of removing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is why are you trying to do a write operation in a read-only transaction? If you are doing a write operation then removing `readOnly=true` is absolutely the right thing to do.

If you are only performing a read then you *should not* remove it. The reason is that having `readOnly=true` improves performance as Hibernate does not need to perform dirty checking for a read-only transaction.

Comment: Thanks.  Answer is that readOnly=true was added by default during the scaffolding process.